# What's the proper way to style an imported React component?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm importing React-RTE and I want to style the elements contained within this component. How can I do this without editing the component itself or doing wonky rules like

```
.Editor > div:nth-child(2)
```

Every element has a className, but they're obviously not usable as displayed in Chrome's or React's DevTools because of the way React handles CSS.

**Example from React DevTools:** className: RichTextEditor__root___2QXK- RecallEditor__reactRTE___WI4hF

What is the proper approach to this issue?